# Have a problem with my traffic light loop

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, graphics2d

```
That's my support class 

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TrafficLightPanel extends JPanel
{
  private JButton red, amber, green, change;
  private JLabel label, label1;
  private JPanel buttonPanel;

  public TrafficLightPanel ()
  {
    red = new JButton ("Red");
    amber = new JButton ("Amber");
    green = new JButton ("Green");
    change = new JButton ("Change");

    ButtonListener listener = new ButtonListener();
    red.addActionListener (listener);
    amber.addActionListener (listener);
    green.addActionListener (listener);
    change.addActionListener (listener);


    buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.setPreferredSize (new Dimension(80, 390));
    buttonPanel.setBackground (Color.white);
    label = new JLabel ("Button Panel");
    buttonPanel.add (label);
    buttonPanel.add (red);
    buttonPanel.add (amber);
    buttonPanel.add (green);
    buttonPanel.add (change);
    label1 = new JLabel ("last pressed");
    buttonPanel.add (label1);

    setPreferredSize (new Dimension(200, 400));
    setBackground (Color.blue);
    add(buttonPanel);

    LightPanel panel = new LightPanel();
    add(panel);
    panel.setPreferredSize (new Dimension(80, 390));
    panel.setBackground (Color.cyan);

  }

  private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
  {
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
    {
      if (event.getSource() == red)
        label1.setText("Red");
      buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.red);
      if (event.getSource() == amber)
        label1.setText("Amber");
      buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.orange);
      if (event.getSource() == green)
        label1.setText("Green");
      buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.green);
      if(event.getSource() == change)
        label1.setText("Change");
      buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.white);
    }
  }

  private class LightPanel extends JPanel
  {
    public void paintComponent (Graphics page)
    {
      super.paintComponent(page);
      page.setColor(Color.red);
      page.fillOval(15, 30, 40, 40);
      page.setColor(Color.orange);
      page.fillOval(15, 90, 40, 40);
      page.setColor(Color.green);
      page.fillOval(15, 150, 40, 40);
    }
  }
}

And that's my application class

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class TrafficLight
{
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Traffic Light");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.getContentPane().add(new TrafficLightPanel());

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

I wanted to ask as my program does exactly what it's suppose to do, however i can't seem to get the loop change label1 to red and at the same time change the buttonPanel background color any suggestions for that?

Comment: Mine also gives a problem - it's always red when I get there.

Comment: The button panels background is always white, right? That's always the last thing you do before you leave actionPerformed: `buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.white);`

Comment: This isn't a bad question per se, but in the future, can you please post the minimal amount of code which reveals your problem? Doing so implies effort on your part and encourages others to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really checked the code , but shouldn't

```
if (event.getSource() == red)
   label1.setText("Red");
   buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.red);
```

be

```
   if (event.getSource() == red)
    {
       label1.setText("Red");
       buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.red);
    }
```

This is why it's a good idea to always use {} , even in single-line conditionals .

Comment: I'm not sure about this comment - _Also don't use == for comparing objects . Always use equals()._

Comment: had to use == it was an example in a class book and yes the {} works perfectly i'll keep that in mind as from now. Thanks heaps was great help

Comment: *"works perfectly"*  ..so we can expect you'll be marking this as the correct answer some time soon?

Answer (score 3):

From what I can see, you need to encapsulate your `if`-statements with `{}` tags, try this:

```
 private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
  {
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
    {
      if (event.getSource() == red)
      {
        label1.setText("Red");
        buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.red);
      }
      if (event.getSource() == amber)
      {
        label1.setText("Amber");
        buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.orange);
      }
      if (event.getSource() == green)
      {
        label1.setText("Green");
        buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.green);
      }
      if(event.getSource() == change)
      {
        label1.setText("Change");
        buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.white);
      }
    }
  }
```

Hope it solves your question!